# How to avoid blank spaces between bars which are plotted next to each other when exporting as SVG from matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, vector-graphics

I am plotting with matplolib a bar chart, where the bars are next to each other without a space in between.

However, when exporting as .svg blank (white) spaces between the bars are visible.
[bar chart with blank spaces between bars when exported as .svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzqpu.png)

When exporting to PDF (also as vector graphic) no blank spaces are shown.
[bar chart without blank spaces between bars when exported as .pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km0u0.png)

Answer (score 1):

If your bars aren't perfectly aligned to pixel boundaries, the SVG renderer will try to antialias them, resulting in lighter patches between adjacent bars.

For example, here are two SVGs that are both 200 pixels wide. The first shows a bar chart with 21 bars. Since the bars are not aligned with pixel boundaries, there are gaps between them. The second has 20 bars. Each bar has integer x coordinates at the left and right edges, and there are no visible gaps.

```html
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
<g fill="#f00">
<!-- Notice the non-integer x coordinates (0.0, 9.5, 19.0, 28.6, etc. -->
<path d="M0.0 50.0V90.0H9.5V50.0Z"/>
<path d="M9.5 42.6V90.0H19.0V42.6Z"/>
<path d="M19.0 35.9V90.0H28.6V35.9Z"/>
<path d="M28.6 30.5V90.0H38.1V30.5Z"/>
<path d="M38.1 26.7V90.0H47.6V26.7Z"/>
<path d="M47.6 25.1V90.0H57.1V25.1Z"/>
<path d="M57.1 25.6V90.0H66.7V25.6Z"/>
<path d="M66.7 28.3V90.0H76.2V28.3Z"/>
<path d="M76.2 33.0V90.0H85.7V33.0Z"/>
<path d="M85.7 39.2V90.0H95.2V39.2Z"/>
<path d="M95.2 46.3V90.0H104.8V46.3Z"/>
<path d="M104.8 53.7V90.0H114.3V53.7Z"/>
<path d="M114.3 60.8V90.0H123.8V60.8Z"/>
<path d="M123.8 67.0V90.0H133.3V67.0Z"/>
<path d="M133.3 71.7V90.0H142.9V71.7Z"/>
<path d="M142.9 74.4V90.0H152.4V74.4Z"/>
<path d="M152.4 74.9V90.0H161.9V74.9Z"/>
<path d="M161.9 73.3V90.0H171.4V73.3Z"/>
<path d="M171.4 69.5V90.0H181.0V69.5Z"/>
<path d="M181.0 64.1V90.0H190.5V64.1Z"/>
<path d="M190.5 57.4V90.0H200.0V57.4Z"/>
</g>
</svg>
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
<g fill="#080">
<!-- Here, the x coordinates are all integers (0, 10, 20, 30, etc.) -->
<path d="M0.0 50.0V90.0H10.0V50.0Z"/>
<path d="M10.0 42.3V90.0H20.0V42.3Z"/>
<path d="M20.0 35.3V90.0H30.0V35.3Z"/>
<path d="M30.0 29.8V90.0H40.0V29.8Z"/>
<path d="M40.0 26.2V90.0H50.0V26.2Z"/>
<path d="M50.0 25.0V90.0H60.0V25.0Z"/>
<path d="M60.0 26.2V90.0H70.0V26.2Z"/>
<path d="M70.0 29.8V90.0H80.0V29.8Z"/>
<path d="M80.0 35.3V90.0H90.0V35.3Z"/>
<path d="M90.0 42.3V90.0H100.0V42.3Z"/>
<path d="M100.0 50.0V90.0H110.0V50.0Z"/>
<path d="M110.0 57.7V90.0H120.0V57.7Z"/>
<path d="M120.0 64.7V90.0H130.0V64.7Z"/>
<path d="M130.0 70.2V90.0H140.0V70.2Z"/>
<path d="M140.0 73.8V90.0H150.0V73.8Z"/>
<path d="M150.0 75.0V90.0H160.0V75.0Z"/>
<path d="M160.0 73.8V90.0H170.0V73.8Z"/>
<path d="M170.0 70.2V90.0H180.0V70.2Z"/>
<path d="M180.0 64.7V90.0H190.0V64.7Z"/>
<path d="M190.0 57.7V90.0H200.0V57.7Z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

(Alternatively, you could try adding `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to your SVG. This disables antialiasing altogether, so it might cause other problems.)